# Can you explain this power-series factorization?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and consider the power series
$$
f_\pm = (1+y^2)^{1/2}x \pm y \quad\text{ and }\quad
g_\pm = x \pm (1 - x^2)^{1/2}y,
$$
in the ring $k[[x,y]]$.
We can use the $\mathbb N$-"grading" on $k[[x,y]]$ to see that these four elements are irreducible: the degree-one part of $f_\pm$ and $g_\pm$ is $x \pm y$, which is irreducible.
Evidently these power series satisfy the relation
$$
f_+\cdot f_- = x^2 - y^2 + x^2y^2 = g_+\cdot g_-.
$$
Therefore, since $k[[x,y]]$ is a UFD, these two factorizations ought to be the same up to units; that is, it ought to be the case that either

1. there are units $u_\pm$ with $f_\pm = u_\pm g_\pm$, or
2. there are units $v_\pm$ with $f_\pm = v_\pm g_\mp$.

**Question**: 
Which of 1 or 2 is the case? What are $u_\pm$ (or $v_\pm$)? How do you see directly that one of these power series divides the other?

**Source**: I arrived at this question when I was studying singularities of plane algebraic curves by completing the coordinate ring at the singularity. The factorization above shows that the coordinate ring $k[x,y]/(x^2 - y^2 + x^2y^2)$ of the curve $C : x^2 - y^2 + x^2y^2 = 0$ becomes isomorphic to $k[[s,t]]/(st)$ upon completion at $(x,y)$: we can take $s = f_+$ and $t = f_-$ (or $s = g_+$ and $t=g_-$). So "formally locally", this singularity is the same as that of two lines crossing.

**Updates**: Lubin showed that only case 1 is possible: multiplying a power series by a unit can only change the monomial term up to a constant factor. (This is obvious, and I shouldn't have missed it!)

Comment: I don't have anything to say about your main question, but I believe you are implicitly making a choice when you write "$(1+y^{2})^{1/2}$", more precisely $1 + \frac{1}{2}y^{2} - \frac{1}{8}y^{4} + \dotsb$ and not its negative, and this should determine whether case 1 or 2 holds.

Comment: That's a good point -- I was implicitly taking the positive root, close to 1.

Answer (score 1):

The very partialest answer, but:

It’s perfectly clear that it’s Case 1 that holds, since $f_+\equiv x+y\pmod{(x,y)^2}$ and $g_-\equiv x-y\pmod{(x,y)^2}$, and there’s no constant that multiplies $x+y$ into $x-y$.

As for a unit power series $U(x,y)$ for which $\,f_+U=g_+$, you can compute
$$
U(x,y)\equiv1-\frac12xy-\frac18(x^3y-x^2y^2-xy^3)
-\frac1{16}(x^5y-x^4y^2+x^2y^4+xy^5)\pmod{(x,y)^8}\,,
$$
and I assure you that the signs inside the parentheses are correct. I was ready to work out the degree-$8$ terms, but I don’t think that seeing them would help one’s understanding any.

I stared at the situation, but don’t see any plain way of getting the existence of $U$. Maybe someone else with clearer vision can see the way.

Comment: I see. I figured that you could compute the first few terms of $U$ by hand but I was afraid to do this -- thank you!